# Angular2 no error response

Tags: angular

I try to catch some error codes of my rest web service:

```
return this.http.put('/mandators/' + mandator.uuid, {name: mandator.name})
            .map(res => {
                console.log(res.status);
                res.json();
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.log(error.status);
                return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
            });
```

When the server return `200` i get also the output on the console but if for example `409` code is returned it only shows me `0`. I am using rc6. Anybody an idea?

Output:

```
Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }
```

Comment: `console.log(error)` what it gives when 409?

Comment: @micronyks i added the output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to use the `subscribe` function since it's much more cleaner. If I where in you I'll do something like this:

```
return this.http.put('/mandators/' + mandator.uuid, {name: mandator.name})
            .map(res => {
                console.log(res.status);
                res.json();
            })
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('yay')
            );
```

**EDIT**
I was using Angular2 rc5, I've just updated to rc6 and now, after some refactoring this is my working code:
service.stream.ts

```
...
getStreams() : Observable<Stream[]>{
         // ...using get request
         return this.http.get(this.streamsUrl)
                        // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         //...errors if any
.catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
...
```

stream.component.ts

```
loadStreams(){
        // Get all comments
         this.streamsService.getStreams()
                           .subscribe(
                               streams => this.streams= streams, //Bind to view
                                err => {
                                    // Log errors if any
                                    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I already tried that with no luck. still getting status code 0. See my updated question for the output

Comment: maybe it´s a bug in the new release?

Comment: I'm using angular2 rc6 in production and I don't have this problem. In lunch break I'll investigate deeper

Comment: could you please be so kind an post just a sample from your production code? it simple doesn´t work

Comment: I was using rc5, I update the production code and edit my answer, I hope this can help you

Comment: i had to change the `error.json().error` just to `error` because sometimes there is no json in my response. Otherwise it works now thanks!!